# Docker Apache installation fails

Tags: apache, docker, debian, httpd.conf

I am trying to start apache service with **docker-compose up**, but I get this error:

```
apache_1  | AH00526: Syntax error on line 15 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
apache_1  | Invalid command 'DirectoryIndex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

This is my Dockerfile for httpd:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

This is my httpd.conf file:

```
ServerName localhost

LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

LoadModule mpm_event_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: make sure mod_dir is enabled

Comment: Thanks, added it, but now Require is a problem.

Comment: You will probably need to add mod_authz_core module as well
`LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so`

Comment: Still I get this:
prototip_apache_1 exited with code 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure you load the mod_dir module

```
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
```

Comment: I tried with LoadModule dir_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so and it works, but now Require is a problem. I guess I am missing all other modules. Do you know where can I get a clean default httpd.conf file with the main modules? I need only modules for php, mysqli, ssl.

Comment: I used that one, but I get another error: apache_1  | AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/local/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist